# How to use UTF-8 folder names in download_html and download.file

Tags: r, web-scraping, encoding, utf-8

I would like to scrape country-specific information from a Chinese webpage into folders that are named according to these countries. Since I am extracting the list of countries from the Chinese page as well, the folder names would contain Chinese characters - which seems to be problematic.

My code is

```r
url <- "https://www.baidu.com/"

path <- file.path("中国", "江苏")
dir.create(path, recursive = TRUE)

download_html(url, file = file.path(path, "baidu.html"))
download.file(url, destfile = file.path(path, "baidu.html"))
```

The error message of the last line reads

```
Error in download.file(url, destfile = file.path(path, "baidu.html")) : 
  cannot open destfile '<U+4E2D><U+56FD>/<U+6C5F><U+82CF>/baidu.html', reason 'Invalid argument'
```

so it seems that `download.file` converts Chinese characters internally. Interestingly, `file.path` has no issues creating folders containing Chinese characters. I am running Windows 10 64 bit and R version 4.0.2.

Is there a way (or alternative function) that accepts Chinese characters or coerces `download.file` to use the correct encoding? If not, what alternatives do I have? I could think of:

1. navigating into the folder using `setwd` (which does work but forces me to use a loop)
2. converting the Chinese names, for example by using its romanization (which is ambiguous and probably does not exist as an R function)

EDIT:
Perhaps this is part of a bigger issue on my machine. The first line of the following code works (i.e. shows `"two"` as a result), whereas the second line does not:

```r
stringr::str_replace_all("one", c("one" = "two"))
stringr::str_replace_all("阿富汗", c("阿富汗" = "Afghanistan"))
```

Instead, the second line produces an error similar to the one above:

```
Warning message:
unable to translate '<U+963F><U+5BCC><U+6C57>' to native encoding
```

However, when I create a string containing Chinese characters, the result seems to be in UTF-8:

```r
string <- "阿富汗"
stringi::stri_enc_isutf8(string)
```

shows `TRUE`.

EDIT 2:
On my old laptop running Ubuntu, `stringr::str_replace_all()` works just fine with Chinese characters.

Answer (score 0):

I think the leading cause of your error during download.file is that your default encoding of Chinese in Windows is UTF-16. I have done some trials and meet similar errors about `download_html`. But I couldn't reproduce the same error. However I think its essence is the same as `download.file`. My problem is that download_html only can discern `file` in arguments which includes Chinese character in UTF-8. The code as below:

```
library(xml2)
url <- 'https://www.baidu.com/'

path <- file.path('中国', '江苏')
dir.create(path, recursive = TRUE)

download_html(url, file = file.path(path, 'baidu.html'))
download.file(url, destfile = file.path(path, "baidu.html")
```

The error occurred:

```
Error in curl::curl_download(url, file, quiet = quiet, mode = mode, handle = handle) : 
  Failed to open file C:\Users\16071098\Documents\涓浗\鍖椾含\baidu.html.
```

But when I change the command about download_html like below:

```
download_html(url, file = enc2utf8(file.path(path, 'baidu.html')))
download.file(url, destfile = enc2utf8(file.path(path, "baidu.html")))
```

It is okay.
Your error shows your Chinese part in path is encoded by UTF-16.
No matter what reason, I think it results from that your default encoding type is different from the function's accepted type.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give the `Encoding` function a try. Can you reproduce the error that I get by comparing `stringr::str_replace_all("one", c("one" = "two"))` and 
`stringr::str_replace_all("阿富汗", c("阿富汗" = "Afghanistan"))`?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce it.  But I advise you to use `Encoding` to check what is the encoded type of  '阿富汗'.  Because in my development env, I have below result:
```>x <- '阿富汗'
>Encoding(x)
[1] "unknown"
>x <- enc2utf8(x)
>Encoding(x)
[1] "UTF-8"
stringi::stri_enc_isutf8(x2)
[1] FALSE
>stringi::stri_enc_isutf16be(x2)
[1] TRUE
```
I am not familiar with `stringi`,  so I am not sure why its type checked out is different from that read by `Encoding `. BTW, in my previous commant `file = Encoding(file.path(path, 'baidu.html')` should be `file = enc2utf8(file.path(path, 'baidu.html')`